# Why are all functions $\{0,1\}^t \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ expressable as polynomials?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, polynomials

Siegelmann, *Neural Networks and Analog Computation*, p. 41, considers an arbitrary function $\beta(d_1,\ldots,d_t)$ : $\{0,1\}^t \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, and assumes that it can be expressed as a polynomial--a linear combination of products of zero or more $d_i$'s:

$$\beta(d_1,\ldots,d_t) = c_1 + c_2d_1 + \cdots + c_{t+1}d_t + c_{t+2}d_1d_2 + \cdots + c_{2t}d_1d_2\cdots d_t$$

I don't yet understand why every such function $\beta$ can be expressed in this way.  Why does this follow merely from the fact that $\beta$ is a map from $\{0,1\}^t$ to $\{0,1\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to associate a monomial with each input vector, and then just add up the monomials to get the desired polynomial.  For example, if you want $(0,1,1,0,1)\mapsto 1$, the monomial is $$(1-d_1)d_2 d_3 (1-d_4) d_5.$$  If instead you want $(0,1,1,0,1)\mapsto 0$, the monomial is $$1-(1-d_1)d_2 d_3 (1-d_4) d_5.$$